# OnClickListener Cannot resolve symbol error

Tags: android, onclicklistener

I am making my first Android app, but I can't continue.
I want to make 2 buttons for play and stop, but when I test it, I get the error "cannot resolve symbol".

```
    import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
```

.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps_create_new_path);



    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    {
        checkUserLocationPermission();
    }

    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    Button ButtonStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ButtonStart);
    Button ButtonEnd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ButtonEnd);
    int count = 0;
    if (count == 0)
    {
        ButtonEnd.setEnabled(false);
        ButtonStart.setEnabled(true);
    }

    ButtonStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){public void onClick (View v) {next_page(v);}});
    ButtonEnd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {public void onClick (View v) {next_page(v);}});


    }

public void next_page(View v){


    switch(v.getId())
    {
        case R.id.ButtonStart:
            count++;
            ButtonStart.setEnabled(false);
            ButtonStart.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            ButtonEnd.setEnabled(true);
            ButtonEnd.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;

        case R.id.ButtonEnd:
            count--;
            ButtonStart.setEnabled(true);
            ButtonEnd.setEnabled(false);
            ButtonEnd.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            ButtonStart.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;

    }
}
```

The error is for count, ButtonStart and ButtonEnd inside switch.

If i put the the lines

```
Button ButtonStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ButtonStart);
    Button ButtonEnd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ButtonEnd);
    int count = 0;
```

outside onCreate() the error is gone but the app does not open this page and it stops when i press the button to bring me to this activity.
This is only the part of the code that has to do with my problem.

Comment: Keep only,   int  count =0;  outside the OnCreate since it needs to be accessed from outside the oncreate in the next_page function.

Comment: I did it and the error about count is gone, but it is still there for ButtonStart and ButtonEnd.

Comment: have u declared the buttons globaly ?, with findViewById inside the oncreate

Comment: Ok i found it. I just add Button ButtonStart, ButtonEnd; outside onCreate; Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> outside onCreate then the error is gone

Making the count and the buttons as fields is correct. They need to be scoped variables outside of onCreate

> but the app does not open this page

I think it does **attempt to open** because you said you're able to click the button

> and it stops when i press the button to bring me to this activity

You need to inspect the logcat to know why the Activity doesn't open

I would suggest temporarily removing the Map Fragment from your Activity, inspect the XML you're loading in onCreate and ensure both those ids you're trying to find are in fact in that XML file

Also, Java variable names nor XML ids should start with capital letters